# Would Ireland visa application affect a German student visa application?

Tags: germany, student-visa, study, ireland

I applied for an Ireland visa under Conference/Event sometime back. My visa not refused, but it was not granted and I was given the right to appeal and included missing documentation. I did not appeal because, by that time, the conference deadline had passed. The Consulate of Ireland consulate did stamp my passport as having applied.

Now, I am planning to apply for a German student visa and I want to know whether my previous visa status would have an affect on this visa application.

Comment: It won't have an automatic effect, but officials will take it into consideration when deciding on your application. The fact that you didn't pursue the application after your travel date passed is perfectly reasonable, so it is unlikely to lead to any negative inference. If the need for additional documents was related to something negative in your history, however, you won't be able to get past that; it's part of your history.